# Trying to convert xmlNodeList to DateTime

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to convert a xmlNodeLIst into a DateTime so that i can place it into my SQL statement and for some reason it just wont work, any help is appreciated.
the code is as follows:
Child4 is the xmlElement in my forLoop

```
// variables
XmlNodeList EventName;
XmlNodeList StartTime;
string EventGUID;

EventName = child4.GetElementsByTagName("event-name");
StartTime = child4.GetElementsByTagName("start-time");
EventGUID = child4.GetAttribute("guid");
DateTime EventDate = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(child4.GetElementsByTagName("start-time"));
```

Comment: Please specify 'it just wont work'. Is an exeption thrown? Do you get any values with `child4.GetElementsByTagName("start-time")`? What kind of value is it? Is it comaptible with any overload of [XmlConvert.ToDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.todatetime?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: @nilsK the error is cannot convert from xml.xmlNodeList to string
the value i get is a date and time in the format of ISO8601

Comment: `child4.GetElementsByTagName` returns a collection of XmlNodes, i.e: an `XmlNodeList`, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist?view=netcore-3.1). You'll need to get 'that one element you need' and then get its value (string) - if your collection has only one element, it simple (`.FirstOrDefault()`). This value you can pass to your `ToDateTime` method.

Comment: Your error describes it: 'cannot convert from xml.xmlNodeList to string'. As you try to pass your `xmlNodeList` to `XmlConvert.ToDateTime`.

Comment: @nilsK as its in a foreach loop, i just need it to get the value every time it loops round, im a little confused on how i obtain that value

Comment: Sorry for the delay .. does your `child4` has only one child element with `name=start-time` ? Then `XmlNode StartTimeNode = child4.GetElementsByTagName("start-time").First()` and `DateTime StartTime = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(StartTimeNode["start-time"].InnerText)`.
This is all untested, but should guide you in the right direction - i hope ;)